# Bash create file based on number before string

Tags: bash, awk

Using **`bash`**, how can I transform the following content of a file:

```
1 apple
3 orange
2 cow
```

into a different file that reads:

```
apple
orange
orange
orange
cow
cow
```

Comment: Each word should go in a separate string in the new file.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?  You can do this quite easily with `awk`.

Comment: You could do this using purely Bash (or POSIX sh), if that's a requirement. But why...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution not using `awk`:

```
while read -r count item; do
   for((i=0; i<$count;i++)); do
      echo "$item"
   done
done < input_file > output_file
```

Or something a little bit more exotic:

```
while read -r count item; do
   printf -- "$item\n%0.s" $(seq 1 $count)
done < input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Discover **`AWK`** language:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=$1;i++) print $2 }' file
```

- `$1`, `$2` are the 1st and 2nd field respectively

---

The output:

```
apple
orange
orange
orange
cow
cow
```

Answer (score 1):

another minimalist `awk`

```
$ awk '{while($1--) print $2}' file
```

or for fun

```
$ while read c w; do yes $w | head -n $c; done <file
```